# 3061 Too few parameters.Expected1

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, ms-access-2016

I am getting the Error two few parameters Expected 1.For the below query which I am using in MS Access vba code .I am able to point that Where clause is the reason I am getting this error.But not sure why.

```
strSQL ="SELECT Count(*) FROM  Table_1 INNER JOIN Table_2 ON (Table_2.[F6] = Table_1.[Column1]) WHERE ( (Table_1.[Table1_Date])> DateAdd(month,-1,Date()) );"
    
Set rs = MyDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `GETDATE()` instead of `DATE()`.

Comment: There is a problem with the 'month' parameter in DateAdd. If you are using the built in funcion to get a month from the current date it should be Month(Date()). If instead it is a variable then I suggest using a different name and should be ...DateAdd(" & varmonth & ", -1, Date()));"

Comment: I tried that but it was giving error "GetDate() not recognized"

Comment: @DuncanDrake Using variable worked for me as you have suggested